# How to cast lastlogon from AD to datetime?

Tags: c#, .net

I am retrieving the lastlogon field for Active Directory user accounts. I have noticed in the case of accounts which have not logged on in a long time I get an exception:

```
Exception type: ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
Exception message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Parameter name: index

The code is below:

```
 long lastLogon = (long)sr.Properties["lastLogon"][0];
 DateTime dtLastLogon = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastLogon);
```

Is there a proper way to cast this and handle that exception?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `lastLogon` ? Does it have a value or is it 0 ?

Comment: It has a value of 0, or (never)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message I suspect that the error is actually here:

```
sr.Properties["lastLogon"][0]
```

and not in the conversion to `DateTime`.  I would add a check for the length of `sr.Properties["lastLogon"]` to make sure it has a length of at least 1 before calling `[0]`. What you *do* in that case is up to you.

Comment: Just implemented that. :) Would there be a case where the code will error if the user has not logged in, in a long time, so the timestamp is a large value?

Comment: Yeah.  Based on the error, `sr.Properties["lastLogon"]` is a 0 length array.

Comment: @dotnetdev `fileTime` is a 64-bit number counting ticks since 1601 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime(v=vs.110).aspx   If anything, you'd have problems with this value being too large far in the future.  It's not a delta counting backwards, so values in the past aren't more likely to overflow.

Comment: @dotnetdev I have no idea what values `sr.Properties["lastLogon"][0]` could have, but if `DateTime.FromFileTime` is the right conversion then it can produce any `DateTime` value after 1/1/1601 so an overflow should not be an issue there.